# Log4j usage - how to customize the event ID when logging to Windows Event Log?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm adding windows event logging functionality to an existing Java application and I'd like to utilize event ids(our admin is using them already). Is there a way to specify the event ID when logging with NTEventLogAppender?

Answer (score 1):

From my research so far it seems like there's no way to modify the event ID from the default 4096.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [log4jna](http://log4jna.codeplex.com). It's a replacement for log4j NTEventLogAppender. It doesn't do what you want right now, but it's "this close". If you still need this, we can work on implementing it.